# Excepcion no controlada "System.StackOverflowException" al tratar de modificar una celda de un DataGridView en C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, datagrid

Tengo un DataGridView el cual cuenta entre otras con las columnas "Precio", "cantidad" y "Subtotal" , estoy ocupando el evento "CellValueChanged" del datagridview para que al momento de modificar la cantidad o el precio se actualice la columna de "Subtotal" , el problema esta en que al realizar el cambio en automatico me da este error y no entiendo el por que puede ser, cabe mencionar que hago exacamente el mismo procedimiento en otra tabla y funciona sin problemas, literal solo cambio el nombre del datagridview (el cual actualizo en este codigo), dejo una captura de mi tabla a continuacion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y una captura del error que me lanza al presionar realizar el cambio del valor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo que ocupo, son solo unas lineas por lo que me resulta aun mas raro pues como comento ocupo el mismo metodo para hacerlo en otras tablas

```
 private void DataGridViewEdicion_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (DataGridViewRow fila in DataGridViewEdicion.Rows)
        {

                float a = Convert.ToSingle(fila.Cells["PRECIO"].Value);
                int b = Convert.ToInt32(fila.Cells["CANTIDAD"].Value);
                float subtotal = a * b;
                fila.Cells["SUBTOTAL"].Value = subtotal;
        }
        CalcularTotales();
    }
```

muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Comment: Podrias revisar como esta definida esa columna de "SUBTOTAL" que tenga otra definicion

Comment: Trata de capturar la excepción y verifica el stack del error, eso te puede dar alguna pista.

Comment: @MauricioContreras como la capturo? intente con un try , catch, pero no me deja, sigue rompiendo la ejecucion

Comment: @CarlosUmaña donde checo eso? la columna se genera automaticamente por que el datagridview lo estoy llenando con una consulta de mysql

Comment: ¿Porqué no te deja? ¿Sabes usar objetos de excepción en tus métodos o clases?

Comment: @MauricioContreras pues los e ocupado antes para cosas como esta, pero ahora pongo el try catch y no hace nada, el por que no lo hace pues no lo se

Comment: Tu error tiene sentido, `CellValueChanged` se produce cuando una celda se modifica.. y dentro de este evento, estas modificando una celda, por lo que se dispara el evento y entra en un bucle infinito provocando un StackOverflowException

Comment: El comentario de @Juan Salvador Portugal tiene sentido; sin embargo, probé el código y me responde correctamente. No se dispara la llamada recursiva al modificar el contenido de la celda SUBTOTAL.

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal como lo planteas tiene sentido, pero como comento antes, uso este mismo metodo en otro datagridview para hacer lo mismo, me parece extrano que este falle justo en eso

Comment: Edita tu pregunta con el `try/catch` para ver si hay algun detalle.

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal ademas ahora que lo estoy probando con diferentes valores, el error solo se dispara cuando se trata de actualizar la celda subtotal con un numero (ya sea variable o directamente poniendole un "= 1"  pero al asignar un string a la celda no hay problema

Answer (score 0):

Bueno pues checando diferentes valores, note que en la tabla de la cual genero la consulta de mysql, con la cual lleno el  datagridview, la columna equivalente al "subtotal" la tengo declarada como Decimal en la base de datos, y esto de alguna forma hace que la columna "Subtotal" del DataGridView solo acepte valores de tipo "Decimal", lo mismo aplica para todas las demas columnas, "Nombre" solo acepta "String", "Cantidad" solo acepta "Int", etc, sabiendo esto la solucion fue tan sencilla como cambiar mi variable de float a decimal, dejo el codigo con el arreglo:

```
private void DataGridViewEdicion_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (DataGridViewRow fila in DataGridViewEdicion.Rows)
        {

                decimal a = Convert.ToDecimal(fila.Cells["PRECIO"].Value);
                int b = Convert.ToInt32(fila.Cells["CANTIDAD"].Value);
                decimal subtotal = a * b;
                fila.Cells["SUBTOTAL"].Value = subtotal;
        }
        CalcularTotales();
    }
```

Comment: Excelente. Saludos

Comment: Interesante. Pareciera entonces un efecto del DataBinding a la BD.